# How to differentiate between the methods in api controller in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApiController as follows:

```
public newController:webapicontroller
{
    public void method1()
    public void method2()
}
```

When I call the URL:

> "http://host:port/api/newcontroller/1/2"

from the controller, which method will it hit (method1 or method2)?.  How can I write a method which just takes 2 parameters?

And is there any significance if I prefix the method names with GET and POST as GETmethod1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from what I understand, the method that started with the http verb (like GetX) and has the same number of parameters as the number of parameters in the URL is picked up.

Comment: Yes but when i call "http://host:port/api/newcontroller/1/2"

the method1() is called even if the method doesnt have any get or post .Why is it?

Comment: Because this is the first best method that MVC can match.